# Outputting data to file from for statement in python

Tags: python, file, for-loop, stdout

I'm trying to achieve outputing data to a file which currently is printing the desired output to the screen from a for statement.

I have the below portion which prints out data to the screen without issue. What can I use to have it write to a file instead?

```
search = open ("algo_fg.txt")
for line in search:
    if app in line:
        print (line)
```

I figured since I was in the for statement, it was a bit trickier to have it write to a file. The original algo_fg.txt file in the code above is where the for statement is running through originally.

Answer (score 1):

In short, `open()` returns a file object, and is most commonly used with two arguments: `open(filename, mode)`. The mode can be `r`, `w`, and `a`. `r` is used to read the file, `w` is used to write to the file (delete the original content) and `a` is used to append content to the file (not delete the original content). `r` will be used if it’s omitted

```
search = open ("algo_fg.txt")
fw = open('out', 'w')
for line in search:
    if app in line:
        # print (line)
        fw.writelines(line)
search.close（）
fw.close()
```

You can find more info [in this tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/inputoutput.html).

Comment: Please add some context to your answer. Why and how does this solve the problem? Code only answers are not considered to be of good style

Comment: @LonelyNeuron,I have Improve my answer, thanks~

Comment: Thank you very much! This helped greatly. I hadn't thought to just create another variable and open a new file from there. Thanks again.